# How to bind DataSource using context.bind. Connection pooling etc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I created a simple java project in NetBean 7.0 and added jar file sqljdbc4.jar for MS SQl support.

I created a class where i have created a datasource (code below) for MQ SQL. 
It connects database using the datasource and gets record count (504) successfully. (I have a Product table which has 504 records)

But it throws error when tried binding to Context. Could someone help me to suggest what should i enter to fill up the "???" in the code below?

```
package datasourcetest; 

import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import javax.naming.Context;

import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource;

import java.sql.*; 

import java.util.Hashtable; 

/** 
* 
* @author admin 
*/ 



public class dataSource { 

public static void main(String [] args) 
{ 

SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource(); 

ds.setServerName("admin-PC\\SQLEXPRESS"); 

ds.setPortNumber(1433); 

ds.setUser("sa"); 

ds.setPassword("admin"); 

try{ 

System.out.println("PART 1"); 

Connection con = ds.getConnection(); 

if(con !=null) 

{ 

System.out.println("Connection Success"); 

} 

Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from AdventureWorks.Production.Product") ; 

while(rs.next()) { 

int count = rs.getInt(1); 

System.out.println("Total Record: "+ count); 

} 

/* Bind the DataSource to JNDI so that we can look for the datasource by the name given**/ 

System.out.println("PART 2"); 

Hashtable env = new Hashtable(); 

env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY," ??? "); 

env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, " ??? "); 

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env); 

ctx.bind("jdbc/myDatasource",ds); 

SQLServerDataSource myDs = (SQLServerDataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDatasource"); 

} 

catch(SQLException se) { 

System.out.println("Failed PART 1"); 

} 

catch(NamingException ne) { 

System.out.println("Failed PART 2"); 

ne.printStackTrace(); 

} 

} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out "connecting to a data source":

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/datasource.html

Comment: Thanks - the link is informative but does not say the value for the  INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY and PROVIDER_URL.                     It throws error: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:  ????  [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  ???? ]

Comment: Any solution to the question ?